# Interface CDI wildfly external projects

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

So my idea is to have 3 projects:

1. com.tests.interfaces
2. com.tests.services
3. com.tests.schedulers

com.tests.interfaces basically is:

```
@Remote
public interface IFoo {
    public String test(); 
}
```

com.tests.services is:

```
@Stateless(name = "IFoo")
public class FooBean implements IFoo {

    public String test() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

}
```

I am deploying the "services" project and it works fine using wildfly 24.0.0. Then I am trying to have another .war project called: com.tests.schedulers which looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class TestEjb {

    @EJB(beanName = "IFoo")
    IFoo iFoo;
    
    public void teste() {
        iFoo.test();
    }
    
}

@Singleton
public class ExecutorMainframeProcessamento {

    @EJB
    TestEjb testEjb;

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", dayOfWeek = "*", persistent = false, info ="Test EJB")
    public void atSchedule() {
        testEjb.test();
    }
}
```

But it cant be deployed and this is the relevant part of wildfly's (same server to all .wars) output:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0405: No Jakarta Enterprise Beans found with interface of type 'com.tests.interfaces.IFoo' and name 'IFoo' for binding com.tests.schedulers.TestEjb/iFoo
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer a class in one WAR from a class in another WAR (unless both are in the same EAR).

This is by design!

Note that you can have all your projects in separate JAR files which are put in the same WAR file which then share their classpath when deployed.  This is how it is typically done.  Either convert your projects to Maven projects and refer to artifacts, or have your IDE help you create the single WAR.

Comment: Ok, so If I always would need the jar of the implementation it self. There is no "point" at all using dependency injection since I can't use the same implementation if you look at the point of cross projects/across project. Assuming that you can't or don't want to put them all in the same EAR. Is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure if you understand _why_ dependency injection is a thing in the first place.  The problem is that a given decision for some reason cannot be made at compile time (which `new` requires) and therefore you must have code that does that decision and then additional code to bring that decision from there to the location where you actually need it.  Global variables are a no-no. A common example is configuration strings like "where is my database located, and what username/password should I use?".  CDI cuts through all this and simply provides what you need, where you need it.

Comment: well. If I have an implementation of something and it's under the same container even tho differents .wars why can't I reuse it? Use the same implementation of the same interface. That's why I said CDI. I thought that this was it's job.

Comment: If you just deploy WAR files you are in the servlet specification, which explicitly has it as a goal that different deployments are invisible to each other (my wording).  Shared classes must go in the web container itself.  If you want classes to be shared in your deployment you must go to EAR deployments if your server supports it and then it is the Java EE specification.

Comment: alright. sounds like that I have to study more about. any tips on materials? Thank you!

Comment: The Jakarta EE tutorial is at https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#injection  I have not read this version so I don't know how accessible it is to you

Comment: I've used https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2019/05/18/a-cdi-primer-part-0/ to help explain DI to people who are new to it; hope it helps.

Comment: @laird your tutorial does not cover the situation here. Did you read the question?

Comment: My sincerest apologies for my comment. I was answering the "sounds like that [sic] I have to study more about [sic]. any tips on materials?" comment. I see that my responding must not have been relevant to this comment.